# Node.js file not reading browser.js file in script tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have spent way too much time trying to figure this out but can't!
I'm following a udemy tutorial where he writes the same code as below but it will not connect to the browser file and run the code from the browser environment.

```
let express = require('express')
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb')
let app = express()
let db 
 
app.use(express.static('public'))

//connect mongodb to code
let connectionString = 'mongodb+srv://todoAppUser:PASSWORD@cluster0.jt6vs.mongodb.net/todoAppPractise?retryWrites=true&w=majority' 
  MongoClient.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, client) {

  //updating global variable db 
  db = client.db()
  app.listen(3000)
  console.log("DB connection successfull")
})

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
//load the items submitted to the database as items on front end of list. 
db.collection('items').find().toArray(function(err, item){
  res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple To-Do App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center py-1">To-Do App</h1>
      
      <div class="jumbotron p-3 shadow-sm">
        <form action="/create-item" method="POST">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <input name="item" autofocus autocomplete="off" class="form-control mr-3" type="text" style="flex: 1;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Item</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <ul class="list-group pb-5">
       
        ${item.map(function(items){
          return ` <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <span class="item-text">${items.text}</span>
          <div>
            <button class="edit-me btn btn-secondary btn-sm mr-1">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete-me btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </li>`
        }).join('')}
      </ul>
      
    </div>
    <script src="/browser.js">
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>`)
})
 
})

app.post('/create-item', function(req, res){
  //console.log(req.body.item)
  db.collection('items').insertOne({text: req.body.item}, function(){
    res.redirect('/')  
  })
 
})
```

And on the browser.js file:

```
alert("hello from browser.js")
```

When I load localhost:3000, I should get an alert but whatever I try it is not responding/reading the file.

Comment: You might try to console.log there in your file to see if it's even getting to there.

Comment: You can use the old good way and try to see if the instructor shared his files if yes to compare or test them.

Comment: it's not even picking it up with console.log, so it's not even getting there. Also yes have looked at his code and it still doesn't work but the course is 2 years old so I'm thinking it's not compatible with updates

Answer (score 0):

Please try to import the JS file by using `require` function. It is one of the function in node for import modules. And should have an export function in `browser.js` That's the best practice.

```
let express = require('express')
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb')
let app = express()
let db 
const browser = require('./browser')
 
 browser()
```

After that you can use `browser`

browser.js

```
function test(){
console.log('browser file is working');
}

module.exports = test;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this code give me an error of: Error: Cannot find module 'browser.js'

Comment: @Jude Ferguson ,  I think the `browser.js` file is in another location. Please confirm that. The above written code is only works when the files are placed in the same folder.  If the file is in another folder please correct the path.